# beta-binomial distribution expectation and variance

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

This question is from Statistical Inference
Book by George Casella and Roger Lee Berger. It is chapter 2 question 29(c).

A particularly nasty discrete distribution is the beta-binomial, with pmf

$$P(y=y)=a(\frac{1}{y+a})\frac{\binom{n}{y} \binom{a+b-1}{a}}{n+a+b-1 \choose y+a}$$

where n,a, and b are integers, and y=0,1,2...,n. Use factorial moments to calculate the variance of the beta-binomial.

My attempt: I know I need to solve $EY$ and $EY(Y-1)$. But I don't know how to solve that. These combinatorics are too complicated for me.

Comment: Using the identity that summing the pmf from $y = 0$ to $y = n$ equals to $1$. Try to transform the summand in the form of the Beta-Binomial pmf - i.e. working with the $\binom {n} {y}$ term.

Comment: @BGM I couldn't get it.

Comment: Ok slightly more explicit. By definition $E[Y] = \sum_{y=0}^n y\Pr\{Y = y\}$. In the pmf there note that $\binom {n} {y} = \frac {n!} {y!(n-y)!}$ which we have the $y$ in the denominator for simplification. Consider $y\binom {n} {y} = \frac {n!} {(y-1)!(n-y)!} = \frac {n!} {(y-1)![(n-1)-(y-1)]!} = n \frac {(n-1)!} {(y-1)![(n-1)-(y-1)]!} = n\binom {n-1} {y-1}$, for $y \neq 0$. Therefore it essentially shifted the parameter from $n$ to $n-1$. Next shift the summation index back to $y = 0$ to $y = n-1$, and try to shift the remaining $a, b$ correspondingly to make it in the form of beta-binomial.